# Running imagemagick on Azure with node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, imagemagick

I have a website on Azure and can't seem to run imagemagick.

I have the binaries there, and have changed my javascript files to point to the imagemagick binaries. The binaries seem to be running, but they don't accept any input using stdin. When I try to write to stdin I get an error about the socket being closed

```
Error: This socket is closed.
at Socket._write (net.js:635:19)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:221:10)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:211:5)
at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
at Socket.write (net.js:613:40)
at Duplex.ImageMagick._write (\\100.68.148.84\volume-9-default\f9e21fc24431ae1e3688\d6a9b08558464073a94176eb39d78b10\site\wwwroot\node_modules\imagemagick-stream\index.js:47:17)
at Duplex.<anonymous> (\\100.68.148.84\volume-9-default\f9e21fc24431ae1e3688\d6a9b08558464073a94176eb39d78b10\site\wwwroot\node_modules\imagemagick-stream\index.js:52:12)
at Duplex.g (events.js:175:14)
at Duplex.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Duplex._spawn (\\100.68.148.84\volume-9-default\f9e21fc24431ae1e3688\d6a9b08558464073a94176eb39d78b10\site\wwwroot\node_modules\imagemagick-stream\index.js:184:8)
```

Is there a fix for this? Is it failing because I am running a website and not a cloud service? I know that it is possible to get working somhow, because I've seen a few examples, but the examples are out of date and dont go over server configuration that much

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It works for me in Windows Azure Web Sites. Same thing I just checked in the binaries... hmm. Which module are you using?